# SSL certificate(s) for one domain and one subdomain

Tags: ssl, domain, subdomain

I want to add https to my site. I only need domain validation and I want the cheapest possible option.

I have:

- Server 1 - example.com (IP 1.1.1.1)
- Server 2 - files.example.com (IP
  2.2.2.2)

Users access to example.com and files.example.com is only used serve downloads.

I found Sslmate 'Standard SSL' certificates. They say his standard certificate include:

- One subdomain
- Domain Validation

I asked to them but they told me that this ssl certificate isn't valid for me.

So what I need? Can I use two standard (cheap) ssl certificates (from Ssls, Sslmate or Namecheap) one for server 1 and another for server 2? Or can I use only one of these cheap certificates?

Thank you!

Comment: Having separate certificates for the two domains is perfectly feasible and not at all uncommon.

Comment: You can deploy one certificate on multiple server, not sure if you are aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in using separate certificates(even from different issuers) for separate (sub)-domains. for consistency you may want to use one issuer, but that isn't strictly required.

In theory you can choose from:

1. Two separate certificates for each domain.
2. Multi-domain certificate, which includes both those domains.
3. Wildcard certificate, which normally covers example.com and *.example.com

All of those options would work, but as you want the cheapest solution option 1 is the best fit.

**Side note:** And, the cheapest(FREE!) option is to use LetsEncrypt certificates for your (sub)domains. But that comes on the maintenance price - you'll need to replace certificates every two months, so some sort of automation would be really necessary.